# Python Get Links Script - Needs Wildcard search

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the below code that when you put in a URL with a a bunch of links it will return the list to you. This works well, except that I only want links that start with ... and this will return EVERY link, including ones like the home/back/etc. is there a way to use a wild card or a "starts with" function?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = ""

# Getting the webpage, creating a Response object.
response = requests.get(url)

# Extracting the source code of the page.
data = response.text

# Passing the source code to BeautifulSoup to create a BeautifulSoup object for it.
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

# Extracting all the <a> tags into a list.
tags = soup.find_all('a')

# Extracting URLs from the attribute href in the <a> tags.
for tags in tags:
    print(tags.get('href'))
```

Also, is there a way to export to excel? I am not great with python and I am not sure how I got this far to be honest.

Thanks,

Comment: First thing, I think `for tags in tags` will cause you problems. Try `for tag in tags`.

Comment: Does `tags.get` return a string? If so, you should be able to use `str.statswith` to do exactly what you want. I'll post an answer below shortly.

Comment: this is gonna sound really bad and im sorry, but how do I know if it returns a string? ..still not great with python, thanks

Comment: Don't be sorry. You can insert a line like `print(type(tag.get('href')))` and if it prints `str`, you've got a string.

Comment: Hello, thank you that is very simple, it returns <class 'str'> so yes they are strings.

Answer (score 0):

If `tags.get` returns a string, you should be able to filter on whatever start string you want like so:

```
URLs = [URL for URL in [tag.get('href') for tag in tags] 
        if URL.startswith('/some/path/')]
```

Edit:

It turns out that in your case, `tags.get` doesn't always return a string. For tags that don't contain links, the return type is `NoneType`, and we can't use string methods on `NoneType`. It's easy to check if the return value of `tags.get` is `None` before using the string method `startswith` on it.

```
URLs = [URL for URL in [tag.get('href') for tag in tags] 
        if URL is not None and URL.startswith('/some/path/')]
```

Notice the addition of `URL is not None and`. That has to become before `URL.startswith`, otherwise Python will try to use a string method on `None` and complain. You can read this just like an English sentence, which highlights one of the great things about Python; the code is easier to read than just about any other programming language, which makes it really good for communicating ideas to other people.

Comment: Hello, sorry do I replace my for tag in tags:
    print(tag.get('href')) with the above? or do I replace where the ulr = ' ' is? thank you

Comment: @DefcaTrick You would put this right after tags is created. It should produce a list of URLs, but not print them. For that you need a line like `for URL in URLs: print(URL)`. I don't know what you expect to do by passing an empty string to `requests.get`.

Comment: Hello, I'm sure it is because I am not getting this, but I replaced for tag in tags:
        print(tag.get('href')) with the above and received the error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Comment: @DefcaTrick that means that the tag isn't a link, and doesn't have an href field. `Tag.get` returns `None` in that case instead of the empty string. I've updated my answer to filter out `None`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `startswith()` :

```
for tag in tags:
    if tag.get('href').startswith('pre'):
        print(tag.get('href'))
```

Comment: Hello, I tried running yours and got the following error: >> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith' when replacing pre with 'http' ideally i want to replace it with a full http://www.this.com/video but that didnt work at all. sorry, thank you

Comment: @DefcaTrick According to the error message, it seems that tag.get(‘href’) is None

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated version of your code that will get all https hrefs from the page:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.google.com"

# Getting the webpage, creating a Response object.
response = requests.get(url)

# Extracting the source code of the page.
data = response.text

# Passing the source code to BeautifulSoup to create a BeautifulSoup object for it.
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

# Extracting all the <a> tags into a list.
tags = soup.find_all('a')

# Extracting URLs from the attribute href in the <a> tags.
for tag in tags:
    if str.startswith(tag.get('href'), 'https'):
        print(tag.get('href'))
```

If you want to get hrefs that start with something other than https, change the 2nd to last line :)

References: 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_startswith.htm

Comment: Hello, trying yours I get this error when only changing the url from google > TypeError: descriptor 'startswith' requires a 'str' object but received a 'NoneType'

Answer (score 0):

For your second question:  Is there a way to export to Excel - I've been using a python module [XlsxWriter](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/index.html#).

```
import xlsxwriter

# Create a workbook and add a worksheet.
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Expenses01.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Some data we want to write to the worksheet.
expenses = (
    ['Rent', 1000],
    ['Gas',   100],
    ['Food',  300],
    ['Gym',    50],
)

# Start from the first cell. Rows and columns are zero indexed.
row = 0
col = 0

# Iterate over the data and write it out row by row.
for item, cost in (expenses):
    worksheet.write(row, col,     item)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 1, cost)
    row += 1

# Write a total using a formula.
worksheet.write(row, 0, 'Total')
worksheet.write(row, 1, '=SUM(B1:B4)')

workbook.close()
```

XlsxWriter allows the coding to follow basic excel conventions - I, being new to python, getting this up, running and working was easy with the first attempt.